# Converting an NSString of JSON Data to NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, json

I have an `NSString` that is storing a `JSON` array in the form of a `NSString`. The `NSString` called `colorArray` has the value of:

```
[{ "color":"Red" },{ "color":"Blue" },{ "color":"Yellow"}];
```

I also have a tableview that I would like to import the array into in order to populate the table. The table works if I load the `tableData` into an array like below, but I can't figure out how to convert the `NSString` into an array that can be used to populate the `tableData` like shown below...

Anyone have ideas? Thanks much!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Initialize table data
    tableData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Red", @"Blue", @"Yellow", nil];
}
```

Comment: -1 For asking how to convert JSON into NSArray for the 1000th time

Comment: I think its implicitly converts if to string?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
// Your JSON data:
NSString *colorArray = @"[{ \"color\":\"Red\" },{ \"color\":\"Blue\" },{ \"color\":\"Yellow\"}]";
NSLog(@"colorArray=%@", colorArray);

// Convert to JSON object:
NSArray *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[colorArray dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                      options:0 error:NULL];
NSLog(@"jsonObject=%@", jsonObject);

// Extract "color" values:
NSArray *tableData = [jsonObject valueForKey:@"color"];
NSLog(@"tableData=%@", tableData);
```

Output:

```
colorArray=[{ "color":"Red" },{ "color":"Blue" },{ "color":"Yellow"}]
jsonObject=(
        {
        color = Red;
    },
        {
        color = Blue;
    },
        {
        color = Yellow;
    }
)
tableData=(
    Red,
    Blue,
    Yellow
)
```

The last step uses the special feature of `-[NSArray valueForKey:]`
that returns an array containing the results of invoking `valueForKey:` using the key on each of the array's objects.

Comment: Thanks martin, I will check this out. Does the NSString need to contain the slashes in order for the conversion to work correctly? Thanks again!

Comment: @Brandon: The backslashes were just necessary to define your sample input as a string constant in the sample code.

Comment: @Brandon: I have added some NSLog output to clarify the steps.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *jsonString = ...//String representation of json 
    NSData *jsonData =  [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    //colors is a NSArray property used as dataSource of TableView
    self.colors = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                                                  options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                    error:nil];

}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.colors count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *color = self.colors[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = color[@"color"];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSData * data = [colorArray dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
NSDictionary *JSON = 
    [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data
                                    options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers 
                                      error: &e];

NSArray *tableData = [JSON valueForKey:@"color"];
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using [ios 5 or higher](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5), JSON serialization is built in:

```
NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization 
        JSONObjectWithData:[string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
        options:kNilOptions 
        error:&error];
```

Prior to ios5, you can use [SBJSON](http://jasarien.com/?p=428) to achieve the same:

```
NSArray *jsonObjects = [jsonParser objectWithString:string error:&error];
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to parse your tring in this way :

```
NSString *jsonString = @"[{\"color\":\"Red\" },{\"color\":\"Blue\" },{\"color\":\"Yellow\"}]";
NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

after this you have an array of dictionay to get all the values you have to do loop the array and read each dictionary

```
NSMutableArray *colorsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[jsonArray count]];

for (NSDictionary *colorDictionary in jsonArray) {

    NSString *colorString = [colorDictionary objectForKey:@"color"];
    [colorsArray addObject:colorString];
}
```

Now colorsArray is NSMutableArray like this :

```
 [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Red", @"Blue", @"Yellow", nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data in coming from a webservice:

```
NSArray *tableData = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:request.responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error] objectForKey:"yourKeyForColorArray"];
```