# How to convert an NSString of JSON objects to an NSArray?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsarray, nsjsonserialization

I'm having trouble converting my `NSString` of JSON objects to an `NSArray`.

The `NSArray` object seems to be null.

Here is my NSString JSON code:

```
NSString* retrievedStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

This gives me a printout of:

> {"image_link":"schedule_tien_nguyen.jpg","start_time":"18:00","end_time":"19:00","viet_performer":"","english_performer":"Tien
>   Nguyen","viet_event":"","english_event":"Singing","day":0,"stage":0}
>
> ....

I tried to convert the `NSString` to an `NSArray` using:

```
NSArray *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:
                     [retrievedStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                      options:0 error:&error];
```

However the printout of the jsonObject is **(null)**

I have tried the solutions from here:
[Converting an NSString of JSON Data to NSArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17009877/converting-an-nsstring-of-json-data-to-nsarray) and [How to convert a JSON String into an NSArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17827070/how-to-convert-a-json-string-into-an-nsarray) but it's still printing out null.

The `error` printout states:

> "Garbage at end."

I'm not sure what that means?

Comment: This JSON contains a dictionary not an array, so try to use NSDictionary

Comment: Did you check `error`?

Comment: Avi: I added it in the description

Comment: Check the raw response. It seems that maybe an error or other characters are added after the json. Please check this

Comment: NSLog the `error` if null is returned, it's provided to help you. `if (jsonObject  == 0) {` `NSLog(@"JSONObjectWithData  error: %@", error);` `}` and handle the error.

Comment: See: [Introducing JSON](http://www.json.org).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to read your JSON response. As others have mentioned, it's a `JSON` dictionary, not an `NSArray`. The dictionary may contain arrays, but the object response itself is a dictionary.

```
NSString* retrievedStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString *imageLink = (NSString *)[retrievedStr objectForKey:@"image_link"]
NSLog(@"%@", imageLink);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `NSArray *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];`